# To Update rows (row number wise) in SQL Table by Update Query without using SET keywords in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
 con.Open();

 //loading the image table
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Employee_Reg_Form", con);
 da.Fill(dt);

 //create a new row that will be added
 DataRow r = dt.NewRow();

 //specify the records to save

 //Employee Registeration Codes
 r[0] = EmpRegCodSNtbox.Text;
 r[1] = EmpRegCodtbox.Text;
```

This is for new ROW Insertion. I require you use the similar code but for updating Data in an entire row?
Please suggest.

Comment: entity framework could be able to help you to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowNumber = 10; //put here your code to select the desired record
dt[rowNumber][0] = EmpRegCodSNtbox.Text;
dt[rowNumber][1] = EmpRegCodtbox.Text;
```

Anyway, in your code, you need to do

```
dt.Rows.Add(r);
```

`dt.NewRow()` only creates an empty row, but itn't attached to the rows collection.